# WPF, MVVM. Similar properties binding practice

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I have a question about MVVM.

For example (see image below), there are two playlists.

- User can click play in one of them. In this case Play button of this playlist (let's call it Current Playlist) should be colored and other Play buttons should be disabled
- When user clicks Play, single Storage creates playlist based on list of media specified by user and Loop/Loop Count settings for Current Playlist
- User can change Loop/Loop Count for any playlist. But MVVM should update Storage only if Loop/Loop Count were change for Current Playlist
  [image]

I can create mvvm like this (simplified code):

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public Brush PlayButton1Background { get; set; }
    public Brush PlayButton2Background { get; set; }

    public bool PlayButton1Enability { get; set; }
    public bool PlayButton2Enability { get; set; }

    public bool Loop1 { get; set; }
    public bool Loop2 { get; set; }

    public bool LoopCount1 { get; set; }
    public bool LoopCount2 { get; set; }
}
```

And then bind to this properties. Pretty simple. Or not? If I need to add one more playlist, I will have to add new properties. Not very good.

I've tried the following solution:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public PlayButtonEnability PlayButtonEnability { get; set; }

    public PlayButtonBackground PlayButtonBackground { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        PlayButtonEnability = new PlayButtonEnability(this);
        PlayButtonBackground = new PlayButtonBackground(this);
    }
}

public class PlayButtonEnability
{
    private ViewModel _viewModel;

    public bool this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return OnAirStorage.CurrentPlaylist == index;
        }
    }

    public PlayButtonEnability(ViewModel viewModel)
    {
        this._viewModel = viewModel;
    }
}

public class PlayButtonBackground
{
    private ViewModel _viewModel;

    public Brush this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            if (OnAirStorage.CurrentPlaylist == index)
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.GhostWhite);
        }
    }

    public PlayButtonBackground(ViewModel viewModel)
    {
        this._viewModel = viewModel;
    }
}
```

And Play button's xaml:

```
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding PlayButtonEnability[1]}"
        Background="{Binding PlayButtonBackground[1]}">
```

For Loop/Loop Count there is similar code.

It works, but I want to know are there better practices for such tasks?

Are there other solutions for flexible and easy-supported view model design? Or may be this solution is not very good (then why?) ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sound like You just have to create this playlist as user control :)

Comment: Have you considered creating a playlist class and use a list of playlists in your viewmodel?

Comment: @Silvermind, sounds like another good way to go. Thanks

Comment: @MajkeloDev, It's user control now

Comment: @Silvermind, anyway, to be able to add new playlist without changing viewmodel (i.e. without adding new item to list of playlists by hands) class with indexer is enough good solution, isn't it?

Comment: @Silvermind, I've changed my view models mostly in accord with your comment. Please write it as answer and I'll accept this

Answer (score 0):

If you to create playlist on fly you should have a 
**property List PlayLists** on your **MainViewModel**

keep this in mind when you write ViewModels, don't create dependencies, each ViewModel has to be able to live a stand alone life.

If you need to send messages between ViewModels, use Pub/Sub event Aggregate.

**You Error**

- On Each View Model you need to Implement a INotifyPropertychange
  interface.
- On each Property on Setter you need to throw a PropertyChanged(this,
  new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)). This tells UI to update

Let me know if you need more help.

Best regards
Burim Hajrizaj

Comment: Erm...I'm not completely new to MVVM and WPF. I wrote that my code is simplified. There are no a lot of parts, including INotifyPropertyChange implementation, because it was not major for my question. Thanks for your answer, but it is useless.

Comment: well then ...you wrote wrong code here and asks for opinion. My first thought was to make a proper VM, witch you don't have in this example